# Parsing this special format file

Tags: c#

I have a file that is formatted this way --

```
{2000}000000012199{3100}123456789*{3320}110009558*{3400}9876
54321*{3600}CTR{4200}D2343984*JOHN DOE*1232 STREET*DALLAS TX
78302**{5000}D9210293*JANE DOE*1234 STREET*SUITE 201*DALLAS
TX 73920**
```

Basically, the number in curly brackets denotes field, followed by the value for that field. For example, `{2000}` is the field for "Amount", and the value for it is 121.99 (implied decimal). `{3100}` is the field for "AccountNumber" and the value for it is 123456789*.

I am trying to figure out a way to split the file into "records" and each record would contain the record type (the value in the curly brackets) and record value, but I don't see how.

How do I do this without a loop going through each character in the input?

Comment: "The only way I can think of is to scan through all the characters one by one" uh, yes. That's what any parser is going to do.

Comment: Well, I guess what I am trying to ask is instead of foreach character in the string, is there a smart way using say LINQ or RegEx to assist with the parsing.

Comment: @gunr2171 no need for the snark. OP is clearly asking for a best approach without having to scan the string themselves.

Comment: Is there any chance that your "values" could contain curly braces that need to be escaped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regular expression should get you going:

- Match a literal `{`
- Match 1 or more digts ("a number")
- Match a literal `}`
- Match all characters that are *not* an opening `{`

```
\{\d+\}[^{]+
```

It assumes that the values itself cannot contain an opening curly brace. If that's the case, you need to be more clever, e.g. `@"\{\d+\}(?:\\{|[^{])+"` (there are likely better ways)

Create a [`Regex` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0) and have it match against the text. Each "field" will be a separate match

```
var text = @"{123}abc{456}xyz";
var regex = new Regex(@"\{\d+\}[^{]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (var match in regex.Matches(text)) {
  Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good one. It could be extended to use named groups to more easily grab your fields and values separately like `(?<field>\{\d+\})(?<value>[^{]+)`. See: https://regexr.com/6vj41

Comment: This works, wow, very nice! Thanks Knittl!

Answer (score 5):

A different way to look at it.... The `{` character is a record delimiter, and the `}` character is a field delimiter. You can just use `Split()`.

```
var input = @"{2000}000000012199{3100}123456789*{3320}110009558*{3400}987654321*{3600}CTR{4200}D2343984*JOHN DOE*1232 STREET*DALLAS TX78302**{5000}D9210293*JANE DOE*1234 STREET*SUITE 201*DALLASTX 73920**";
var rows = input.Split( new [] {"{"} , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var fields = row.Split(new [] { "}"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", fields[0], fields[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
2000 = 000000012199
3100 = 123456789*
3320 = 110009558*
3400 = 987654321*
3600 = CTR
4200 = D2343984*JOHN DOE*1232 STREET*DALLAS TX78302**
5000 = D9210293*JANE DOE*1234 STREET*SUITE 201*DALLASTX 73920**
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W0AzEF)

Comment: Thanks John, this works well. I am actually going to select this vs. the RegEx one. This is easier to understand.

Comment: I didn't see this when I wrote my linq version -- basically the same :)

Answer (score 3):

*This doesn't fully answer the question, but it was getting too long to be a comment, so I'm leaving it here in Community Wiki mode. It does, at least, present a better strategy that may lead to a solution:*

---

The main thing to understand here is it's rare — like, **REALLY** rare — to genuinely encounter a whole new kind of a file format for which an existing parser doesn't already exist. Even custom applications with custom file types will still typically build the basic structure of their file around a generic format like JSON or XML, or sometimes an industry-specific format like [HL7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Level_7) or [MARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MARC_standards).

The strategy you should follow, then, is to **first determine exactly what you're dealing with**. Look at the software that generates the file; is there an existing SDK, reference, or package for the format? Or look at the industry surrounding this data; is there a special set of formats related to that industry?

Once you know this, you will almost always find an existing parser ready and waiting, and it's usually as easy as adding a NuGet package. These parsers are genuinely *faster*, need *less code*, and will be *less susceptible to bugs* (because most will have already been found by someone else). It's just an all-around **better** way to address the issue.

---

Now what I see in the question isn't something I recognize, so it's just possible you genuinely do have a custom format for which you'll need to write a parser from scratch... but even so, it doesn't seem like we're to that point yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it in linq without slow regex

```
string x = "{2000}000000012199{3100}123456789*{3320}110009558*{3400}987654321*{3600}CTR{4200}D2343984*JOHN DOE*1232 STREET*DALLAS TX78302**{5000}D9210293*JANE DOE*1234 STREET*SUITE 201*DALLASTX 73920**";



var result = 
  x.Split('{',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
 .Aggregate(new List<Tuple<string, string>>(),
            (l, z) => { var az = z.Split('}');
                        l.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(az[0], az[1]));
                        return l;})
```

LinqPad output:
[image]